# Passive voice and active voice

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, sentence-structure, passive-voice, active-voice

How can I change this sentence from active to passive without changing its structure?

My student has found those words in that thesaurus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Active

> My student has found those words in that thesaurus.

Passive

> Those words in that thesaurus have been found by my students.

Comment: Thank you, would it also be correct to say: Those words has been found in the thesaurus by my students?

Comment: @personallearner No, but you could say *Those words **have** been found in that thesaurus by my students*.